# How to properly denote a pullout on a mobile screen?

Tags: mobile, buttons

I have a pullout that comes from the left side of the screen and is currently denoted with the arrow button below. Is there a standardized way to denote a pullout to make the feature more clear to the user?

[image]

Comment: I think users have become accommodated to the fact that if anything is fixed to the left, right, top or bottom, they will try clicking on it to see what it does. Have you tried user testing this?

Comment: @Majo0od Yes I have and they were able to identify that it was a pullout but not what was on the pullout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the system ones (notifications on both platforms, control centre on iOS and the new app drawer on Android Nougat) **pullouts are not very common** on mobile. There are some apps that have them, though.

I believe the best way to denote it would be to **indicate draggability** not the direction. This is because showing the direction communicates to the user that a specific action will occur, and thus s/he has less control over it - and this may trigger a tendency to tap (unless this is what you want to achieve).

Draggability can be denoted by **showing a drag handle**. A drag handle works in to ways, it can be moved back and forth, and has no specific direction assigned to it.

Here is an example of a drag handle that provides three various states – a map view, a stops view and a mixed view:

[image: Map view]
[image: Stops view]
[image: Mixed view]

What is interesting, **this handle also works on tap**, switching the map and mixed states (and even though in this particular case it is not 100% clear which state it will switch to, the app is very useful as it is anyway). I think it is a good idea to provide this behaviour any time when there are some most probable states to switch between.

**Wrap-up:**

- a handle indicates draggability (with all its imperfection, as an uncommon solution),
- any directional symbol (arrow, chevron, triangle...) indicates sliding in a specific direction on tap (or tap and release),
- it is just a little, useful sin to provide on-tap behaviour for a handle,
- it is a much bigger sin to provide a drag behaviour for a directional symbol.

Comment: Thank you this answer helped greatly. My implementation of the pullout is similar to the one you have used in the example. In this instance would you choose to make the behavior on-tap or a drag behavior?

Comment: In this particular case dragging allows user to just temporarily switch from one view to another (just one back-and-forth slide without actually lifting up the finger), which I have just found to be quite handy (I even did not realise I have been doing it before, but I have). I think it is perfect as it is here, so both tap and drag. But, of course, each case is slightly different, you may find having just one of these to be better. Remember that you can still ask some people to say which one they find more convenient - just run a corridor test ;)